# Bootstrap - how to line up items horizontally without breaking them up?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

See [JSbin example](http://jsbin.com/kucapagoha).

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2>Hi</h2>
        <p>Some text here!</p>
        <ul>
          <li>List</li>
          <li>of</li>
          <li>items</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2>Hi</h2>
        <p>Some text here! This is a bit longer than the others, causing the list to be pushed down and not look so nice.</p>
        <ul>
          <li>List</li>
          <li>of</li>
          <li>items</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2>Hi</h2>
        <p>Some text here!</p>
        <ul>
          <li>List</li>
          <li>of</li>
          <li>items</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I can't figure out how to get the `<ul>`s to all be aligned horizontally (tops). I thought about splitting those into the next row which would work, but when viewing on mobile, it would obviously list all the heading text for each of the three items, followed by three sets of list items.

To illustrate:

[image]

[image]

But the important point here is that when the user views this on an iPad or iPhone, these three "Hi" items will stack on top of each other, so any added space via `height` or `min-height` will look pretty bad.

Comment: What do you mean by aligned top? The items will obviously be pushed down if they have text above them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix is to put headline and associated text into a wrapper and give it a `min-height`

HTML:

```
<div class="headline">
    <h2>Hi</h2>
    <p>Some text here!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.headline { min-height: 100px; }
```

That will keep the list aligned, as long as no `.headline` goes over the min-height.

A different solution would be using Javacript to dynamically adjust the heights of the headlines to equal the highest of them.

Comment: That would work, but it looks bad when going from desktop to iPad (when the items collapse into a single column).

Comment: You can change it to only happen on bigger screens: `@media (min-width: 600px) { .headline { min-height: 100px; } }` (change 600px to iPad size or a less/sass variable)

Comment: Oh duh! Why did I not even think of that :) Thank you. I've been spending too much time coding this thing, my brain is tired.

Comment: Yes, but it's easier to think the other way around (mobile first): The min-height does not exist, unless the screen is wider than defined in the media query.

Answer (score 0):

CSS CODE:

```
li{display: inline;}/*to align horizontal list*/
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the issue. See the JSbin and shrink the browser width. I need the top of each UL to line up horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the col-xs-4 class rather than col-sm-4. sm won't work on  small mobile screens. see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: If `col-xs-*` is not specified, `col-xs-12` is assumed.

Comment: oh, my bad, I misunderstood the question.